# my first trigger. Please help me

Tags: apex, trigger

I was asked to write a trigger for a workflow rule. the issue is that the email alert is going out even with the Initial Field Visit date field is filled in  if this field is filled in then the email should not be going out.   I was told the only way to update the child record from the Parent is to write a trigger.  so here I am....  so far this is the code I have for my trigger.  please take a look and all suggestions are welcome.

```
trigger FieldVisitComplete on Lead_Source__c (after insert, after update) {
    List <Opportunity> parentObjList = new List<Opportunity>();
    List <Id> listIds = new List<Id>();
    List <CompleteDate>Visitdate = new List<CompleteDate>();

    for (Lead_Source_c childObj : Trigger.new)
    {
        listIds.add(childObj.Effort__r.Id );
        Visitdate.put(Lead_Source_c);
    }
    Map<Id, opportunity> parentObjList = [Select id,Effort_r.Initial_Field_Visit_Completed_c FROM Opportunity WHERE ID IN :listIds]; 

    for (Opportunity opp : parentObjList) {              
        if (Effort_r.Initial_Field_Visit_Completed_c != null) {
            return value from Effort_r.Initial_Field_Visit_Completed_c;
            merge Effort_r.Initial_Field_Visit_Completed_c into Lead_Source_c;    
        }  
    }

    {
        update parentObjList; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it working? Are you getting a compile error?

Comment: it's not working. for this line: Map<Id, opportunity> parentObjList = [Select id,Effort_r.Initial_Field_Visit_Completed_c FROM Opportunity WHERE ID IN :listIds]; I get the following error: didn't understand relationship 'Effort_r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationshp, be sure to append the '_r" after the custom relationship name. what does that mean?????

Comment: What is the relationship between Effort and Lead Source objects?

Comment: Effort(originally Opportunity) is the parent.   Lead Source is the child object

Comment: @user8571 1) it is a __r(double underscore) and not _(single underscore) 2) __r means a lookup field and the error didn't understand relationship 'Effort_r' in field path means either the Opportunity does not have a effort__r lookup field (or) the api name is being used incorrect in your query. Looking at the error message position it is very clear that Effort does exist and you have used an _ instead of __r which is causing the error

Comment: if Effort__r was not a valid field you would have seen the error message at  listIds.add(childObj.Effort__r.Id ); even after you fix I am seeing multiple errors which needs to be fixed one by one

Comment: What is the API name of the field on the Lead Source object that would indicate the visit is completed?

Comment: And where was your workflow rule, on the Lead Source object?

Comment: It looks like there are several other instances of single-underscore where it should be double. __c is always the last 3 chars of a custom field name.

Comment: the API name on the lead source object is Initial_Field_Visit_c.  the workflow rule is on the Lead Source Object.  the parent object is Effort(Opportunity).  I also noticed the fields exist but they are not on the page layout.  Do i need the fields in the page layout in order to make the trigger work?   It sounds like a simple question but I want to make sure.  thanks again for all the help you guys are giving.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to Effort_c lookup field definition and check children relationship name. This is a sample and hope that help you. [image: Field Relationship]