# My first Trigger - Part 2

Tags: apex, trigger

Good morning Everyone,
Last week I published my first post asking for help on my very first trigger: 
[1st Trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37061/my-first-trigger-please-help-me/37089#37089)

well I have made changes but still running into problems.  I have attached below my latest updates but can't understand why I continue to get the message:

> Illegal assignment from SOBJECT:Opportunity to SOBJECT:Lead_Source__c

Which is on line 15: `Lead_Source__ lsrc = parentObjList.get(opp.Id);`

```
trigger FieldVisitComplete on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

    Set <Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>(); 

    for (Opportunity parentObj : Trigger.new)
    {
        oppIds.add(parentObj.Id);
    }

    Map<Id, Opportunity> parentObjList = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([Select Initial_Field_Visit_Completed__c FROM Opportunity WHERE ID IN :oppIds]); 

    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
    if (opp.Initial_Field_Visit_Completed__c != null) {
            Lead_Source__c  lsrc  = parentObjList.get(opp.Id);
            lsrc.Initial_Field_Visit__c = opp.Initial_Field_Visit_Completed__c;
        }  
    }

    {
        update parentObjList; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, yes, I want the field in the opportunity object, which is the parent object, to talk to the child object Lead source.  the field in opportunity called initial field visit completed, once this field is completed I want it to update on the child object record Initial field visit.  also, does the initial field visit field need to be on the page layout for this to work?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are assigning an Opportunity Object to a Lead Source.  I'm not sure what your end goal is... but I can make 2 guesses.  For someone to help you out better, we need more info but I know what your exact error is:

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> parentObjList 

Lead_Source__c  lsrc  = parentObjList.get(opp.Id);
```

Insert lead sources:

```
trigger FieldVisitComplete on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
  List<Lead_Source__c> newSources = new List<Lead_Source__c>();

  for (Opportunity opp: Trigger.new) {
    if (opp.Initial_Field_Visit_Completed__c != null) {
      Lead_Source__c  lsrc  = new Lead_Source__c(Parent_Id__c = opp.Id);
      lsrc.Initial_Field_Visit__c = opp.Initial_Field_Visit_Completed__c;
    }  
  }

  insert newSources;
}
```

Update existing LeadSources:

```
trigger FieldVisitComplete on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
  Map<Id, Lead_Source__c> sourceMap = new Map<Id, Lead_Source__c>();
  for (Lead_Source__c source: [SELECT Initial_Field_Visit__c FROM Lead_Source__c WHERE Opp_Id__c IN :Trigger.new])
    sourceMap.put(source.Opp_Id__c, source);

  for (Opportunity opp: Trigger.new) {
    if (opp.Initial_Field_Visit_Completed__c != null) {
      Lead_Source__c  lsrc  = sourceMap.get(opp.Id);
      lsrc.Initial_Field_Visit__c = opp.Initial_Field_Visit_Completed__c;
    }  
  }

  update sourceMap.values();
}
```

EDITED ANSWER FROM NEW INFO BELOW:

```
trigger FieldVisitComplete on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
  Map<Id, List<Lead_Source__c>> sourceMap = new Map<Id, List<Lead_Source__c>>();
  for (Lead_Source__c source: [SELECT Initial_Field_Visit__c FROM Lead_Source__c WHERE Opp_Id__c IN :Trigger.new AND Opp_Id__r.Initial_Field_Visit_Completed__c  != null])
  {
    List<Lead_Source__c> sources = sourceMap.get(source.Opp_Id__c);
    if (sources == null)
    {
      sources = new List<Lead_Source__c>();
      sourceMap.put(source.Opp_Id__c, sources);
    }
    sources.add(source);
  }

  List<Lead_Source__c> updatedSources = new List<Lead_Source__c>();
  for (Opportunity opp: Trigger.new) {
    if (opp.Initial_Field_Visit_Completed__c != null) {
      List<Lead_Source__c> lsrcs = sourceMap.get(opp.Id);
      for (Lead_Source__c source: lsrcs)
      {
        lsrc.Initial_Field_Visit__c = opp.Initial_Field_Visit_Completed__c;
        updatedSources.add(source);
      }
    }  
  }

  update updatedSources;
}
```

Comment: the goal:  there is a workflow rule on the child object (lead source) that automatically sends out an email alert.  the email alert should not go out if an Initial Visit Completed date has been entered on the parent object (opportunity) salesforce support says in order to update the child record from the parent and have it fire the workflow rule it would be to use a trigger.

Comment: So, there could be multiple Lead_Sources per Opportunity?  How would we know which one should be getting updated?  Or do all of them need updated?

Comment: there is are multiple lead sources.  this should update all if the field in Opportunity object has been completed.

Comment: Added new info based on what you told me.

Comment: thanks dphil!  question, does it matter if the field titled Initial Field Visit is NOT on the page layout?

Comment: Nope.  Triggers aren't effected by page layouts.

Comment: I ask because the problem line i get now is:  No such column' Initial_Field_Visit__c on entity Lead_Source__c.  not sure what I can do now.

Comment: That means your **Lead_Source__c** object does not have an **Initial_Field_Visit__c** field on it.  Is that actually a field on the Opportunity and not the Lead source?  I don't have visibility into your org, so I only have guesses.

Comment: thank you for your help dphil.  i just noticed the field is not in my sandbox but it is on my production page.  it must have been added in production only.  If i add the field in sandbox I assume everything should work.

Comment: code didn't work.  thanks anyway for trying to help.

Comment: Thing is, I know that code will do what you want.  If you simply copy/pasted it, it definitely won't work.  I made up names from the relationships since you never described what they were.  You need to fix those names yourself.  If there was something else wrong, it simply needs a minor fix.

Comment: ok.  got it.  thanks dphil, as you can tell I'm new at this. :)